# SSH asking for password in Bluemix

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, ssh-keys, ibm-cloud

I am having issues trying to access my VM in Bluemix. Here are my steps:

I tried two ways:

- ask Bluemix web page to make a secure key and download it, or
- generate in my computer and send it to Bluemix web page.

Everything I try results in the same issue: when I ssh into any of my VMs it keeps asking for my password, but Bluemix has no default password and doesn't ask the user to create an access password.

I am using ibmcloud user as I read in other questions. Another point: I know at least two more people having the same problem in their machines. Is there a general problem? Can you help me determine the solution to this error?

**Update with console output**:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/ibmclound.pub ibmclound@129.41.xxx.xxx 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/claudino/.ssh/ibmclound.pub': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/claudino/.ssh/ibmclound.pub': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/claudino/.ssh/ibmclound.pub': 
ibmclound@129.41.xxx.xxx's password: 
Permission denied, please try again. 
ibmclound@129.41.xxx.xxx's password:
```

Comment: Guys, this is the console output:

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/ibmclound.pub ibmclound@129.41.xxx.xxx`  
`Enter passphrase for key '/home/claudino/.ssh/ibmclound.pub': `  
`Enter passphrase for key '/home/claudino/.ssh/ibmclound.pub': `  
`Enter passphrase for key '/home/claudino/.ssh/ibmclound.pub': `  
`ibmclound@129.41.xxx.xxx's password: `  
`Permission denied, please try again.`  
`ibmclound@129.41.xxx.xxx's password: `

Answer (score 4):

You should have received a `.pem` file, mine is `Ubuntu.pem`.
First do a `chmod 600` so that the key is not ignored.

```
chmod 600 /home/someone/Downloads/Ubuntu.pem
```

Then:

```
ssh ibmcloud@the_ip_of_your_VM -i /home/someone/Downloads/Ubuntu.pem
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you aren't specifying your SSH key file when you are attempting to connect over SSH. The command should look something like this:

`ssh -i path/to/keyfile user@server`

If that doesn't work try specifying the verbose option `-vvv` to get some logging information from the ssh command, and then edit your question to add that information.

Comment: @AndréClaudino That looks like your local key file is password protected, and you aren't entering the password so the key file can be read. Also, if you look at Olivier's answer, you should be using a .pem file instead of a .pub file.

Comment: thanks @mbaird, but I tried both pem and pub (I extracted pub file from the pem key).

Comment: I've also give the chmod 600, the problem keeps.

Comment: @AndréClaudino Is your key file password protected? Looking at your console output, either the key file is password protected and you aren't entering the correct password, or there is something wrong with your key file. You might try downloading it again.

Comment: @AndréClaudino also, try capturing the console output when you use the .pem file, and add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

@AndreClaudino the user id is "ibmcloud" and per your first post above it seems you are using "ibmclound" instead.

Please try using ibmcloud user id.

Comment: Soty, I think I wrote it wrong here, but I wrote it correctly in command line.